# Why veracode detects that ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings') call contains an argument injection flaw?

Tags: php, drupal-7, veracode

While scanning the Drupal code I received this message "This call contains an argument injection flaw. The argument to the function is constructed using user-supplied input
without properly delimiting or sanitizing it."
It refers to:

```
$default_line_endings = TRUE;
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', (bool) $default_line_endings);
```

I'm using it inline in a Drupal module. 
Any ideas what to do to avoid this? I need that variable to be used like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security warning since your ini configuration depends on a variable.

While it doesn't seem like the variable's value actually depends on a user's input, consider to try the following:

```
$default_line_endings = TRUE;
...
...

if(!$default_line_endings)
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', false);
else
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```